# error handler Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm following a node/express course and the instructure has written the below error handler code and I get the error:

*Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body; move the returned value immediately after the `=>`.eslintarrow-body-style*

Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

```
const catchAsync = fn => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        fn(req, res, next).catch(next)
    }
}


exports.createTour = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

    const newTour = await Tour.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            tour: newTour
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ref here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style

So, Depends on your eslint configuration, it could be

```
const catchAsync = fn => (req, res, next) => fn(req, res, next).catch(next)
```

or

```
// return keyword at nested block
const catchAsync = fn => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        return fn(req, res, next).catch(next)
    }
}
```

I guess the fix is the 2nd example